# SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context

Tags: flash, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error 2000 in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754270/error-2000-in-flash)

I receive the dreaded:

> SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context

and nothing else; no other errors or traces, just that message in my debug flash player. Now the code I have inherited for this project is huge so I have no idea where the issue could be. I already knocked out a few security issues by embedding my xml and css during compile, and I've reached a dead end.

I do load swfs dynamically but everything is local to the main swf.

Now I should point out that the customer is loading the swf by simply putting the address of it on a file server into their browser (its not in a web page - yes I know this is bad practice but its what they want).

Any one have anything?

Comment: Well, I'm affraid there's no general reason of a disaster. I'd asked the same question [Error 2000 in flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754270/error-2000-in-flash)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set -use-network=false in Compiler settings AND embed any external files you are acessing such as xml or css.  ALSO is any in any child swfs you are loading into your main swf, they should do the same if they in turn load external assets.